# writing and reading inifiles ordered

Tags: delphi, ini

I want to know how I can write an Inifile so that I can read from it in order.

First of all writing it: Let say I have 2 strings I want to save (Name and Lastname).

This is a button. So it will be clicked everytime:

```
Ini.WriteString(person1, 'Name', Name.text);
Ini.WriteString(person1, 'Lastname', Lastname.text);
```

How can I make this person1, alter everytime a new person is added. so next time person2, person3, etc. How is it possible? Do I have to look at what the previous one said? or can it remember? Maybe if I understand this, reading from the file will go in same maner.

kind regards and thank you

Comment: I think you really need to review your question, as it is not clear what you want to archive.  For example with this `Do I have to look at what the previous one said?`... uh, what previous one? sorry, I don't get it.

Comment: from memory I think ReadNames is the method to call.

Comment: @David: More likely: ReadSectionValues which you provide with the section name and a TStrings descendant that will be filled with the Key-Value pairs in the section.

Comment: ok, if i understand correctly that is for reading the values from the inifile. how about saving in the maner of person1, next click is person 2, next clikc is person 3? thx

Comment: @David: And ReadSections reads all section names in an ini file.

Comment: Those section names might not always be in the natural order you want them in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose you want to store *n* data items in an INI file. I do that all the time -- it's easy. First, saving is trivial, but of course, the exact procedure depends on where you get the data from. If you have two arrays of strings, for example (let's call them `FirstNames` and `LastNames`), then you just do

```
for i := 0 to high(FirstNames) do
begin
  IniFile.WriteString('Names', 'FirstName' + IntToStr(i), FirstNames[i]);
  IniFile.WriteString('Names', 'LastName' + IntToStr(i), LastNames[i]);
end;
```

To read the (unknown number of items), do something like

```
for i := 0 to MaxInt do
  if ValueExists('Names', 'FirstName' + IntToStr(i)) then
    // Do something with ReadString('Names', 'FirstName' + IntToStr(i))
    // and ReadString('Names', 'LastName' + IntToStr(i))
  else
    break;
```

Notice that `'Names'` is the arbitrary name of the section in the INI file under which you store the data.

## Update

If you just want to save items when clicking a button, why not do

```
private
  { Private declarations }
  n: integer;
```

and

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  n := 0;
end;
```

and then

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with TIniFile.Create('myfile.ini') do
    try
      WriteString('Names', 'FirstName' + IntToStr(n), Edit1.Text);
      WriteString('Names', 'LastName' + IntToStr(n), Edit2.Text);
      inc(n);
    finally
      Free;
    end;
end;
```

If you instead would prefer to have a section per item, do

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with TIniFile.Create('myfile.ini') do
    try
      WriteString('Name' + IntToStr(n), 'FirstName', Edit1.Text);
      WriteString('Name' + IntToStr(n), 'LastName', Edit2.Text);
      inc(n);
    finally
      Free;
    end;
end;
```

instead.

Comment: thx, I like the answer, but I don't have the firstnames and lastnames in an array. I have just a button and 2 edit fields. Everytime I click the button, I want the info from the edit fields to be saved, under a new section. And this is the 'string' i want to increase. i tried with inc, but that does work either. do you understand what I mean?

Comment: @Andreas: Are you aware that the underlying order inside the INI file isn't guaranteed, and in fact, is likely to be come ordered in a way that the OP finds confusing, if they actually care about the physical order it is stored into the file in, especially if they delete, and add a few times.  TMemIniFile, and TIniFile do not care about the physical ordering and do not guarantee to the user that the last thing you added will always be last in the file.

Comment: @Warren P: Yes, I am aware of that. I never rely on the ordering of the lines inside each section, and not of the ordering of the sections.

Comment: Perhaps collecting names in a name value pair of a string list, then when closing, calling `WritePrivateProfileSection` would be more robust.

Comment: I think the OP is confused about order, and Andreas may be clear on it, but I doubt the OP is clear about it.

Comment: Please stop using TIniFile and start using TMemIniFile. It works better.

Comment: @David: Thank you for your recommendation.

Answer (score 3):

To get sequential numbering of sections each time you save a person you would have to read all the section names, determine the highest number, increment that and then use it to write the a new section with that name and the new person's values.

Something like:

```
var
  IniFile: TIniFile;
  SL: TStringList;
  i: Integer;
  Highest: Integer;
begin
  IniFile := TIniFile.Create('MyIni.ini');
  try
    SL := TStringList.Create;
    try
      IniFile.ReadSections(SL);
      Highest := 0;
      for i := 0 to SL.Count - 1 do begin
        Highest := Max(Highest, StrToIntDef(Copy(SL[i], Length('Person'), MAXINT), 0));
      end;

      IniFile.WriteString('Person' + IntToStr(Highest), 'Name', Name.Text);
      IniFile.WriteString('Person' + IntToStr(Highest), 'LastName', LastName.Text);

    finally
      SL.Free;
    end;

  finally
    IniFile.Free;
  end;

end;
```

Comment: @Andreas: Nope, my fingers, brain, Delphi IDE and SO editor got themselves all mingled up... Should be better now... :-)

Comment: No, @Andreas, it will be the value of the highest person number. MAXINT in that expression is the third argument to `Copy`, not an argument to `Max`.

Comment: @Rob: Yes, silly mistake of me. (The `0` isn't visible to me without scrolling, so I didn't see it...)

Comment: A closing paren is missing on the `Max` line.

Comment: @Marjan Venema: Sorry to disturb you again, but there's another problem: `SL.WriteString` should probably be `IniFile.WriteString`. And don't ask me please, how I managed to spot the tiny missing parenthesis sooner than this. :) I wouldn't know.

Comment: @Andriy M: You are perfectly right. Just goes to show that you shouldn't write code in the SO editor... And no, I won't ask you how you spotted that parenthesis earlier. Though it would be interesting indeed :-)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that using an ini file to do this is the wrong way to go about it. Ini files are not designed to store things in order. The simplest way of achievng this is to use a TStringList and save and load it to disk.